# Separate blackberry Icon for Blackberry Professional Server Messages?

Tags: blackberry, bes

By default when you setup a phone with BPS/BES, all of the messages from that server go into the messages folder, instead of creating a separate icon for that e-mail account.  I've found this [blackberry KB article that explains how to create a separate icon](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB15003).  However, I can't seem to get it to work with BPS.  Is this possible on a BPS?  If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have to buy a third party application to seperate Personal and Corpoarte mail.

http://www.getempower.com/

This site should help as well:

http://www.blackberryforums.com/bes-admin-corner/111753-how-can-i-separate-corporate-personal-email-blackberry-handheld.html

Comment: Did you read the whole forum post?  The dated forum link you just posted makes reference to the fact after a certain software version this is no longer a limitation... my question is whether or not if this is just a feature of BES and not BPS.

Comment: Sorry, Empower was my answer, I just posted the 2nd link for your reference.

I found reference on this site that states you can't do this with BPS.  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Professional-Software/Separate-email-box-icon/m-p/266762;jsessionid=3E0F779974BB63132DAAC72BFB60343A